# Do both the given sentences mean the same thing?

Tags: sentence-choice

> What better way to show him you're interested in him than **by getting him a present?**
>
> What better way to show him you're interested in him than **with a present?**

Do both the sentences mean the same thing?

Comment: The two sentences do mean the same thing; In the second the 'with' sort of implies the act of getting and giving the present. I'll wait and see if anyone can give a more technical answer!

Answer (score 1):

The sentences don't mean the exact same thing but do have a certain equality. The first sentence has a distinct action while the second one can either mean what the first sentence means or something completely different.

As a non-native speaker I'd rephrase the sentences. However, aa TRomano states **it's perfectly correct the way it is**:

1. What better way is there to show him you're interested in him other than **by getting him a present?**
2. What better way is there to show him you're interested in him other than **with a present?**

Comment: You started out fine, but the answer went south.  OP's two sentences are perfectly idiomatic.  BTW, the action is "to **show** him you are interested", not "to interest him".

Comment: This construction is very common in product ads, especially around gift-giving holidays: *What better way to tell him you love him than with a box of stainless steel nails from Acme Building Products?*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I didn't know that. Without **is there** it seems completely wrong.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22what%20better%20way%20to%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Indeed, thnx. Strangely, it still feels very awkward. I prefer **What better way is there to**

Comment: Existential **there** is being omitted from a fixed rhetorical pattern.  What better way to ... {do something} than ... with|by...

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatical and are practically synonymous though grammatically slightly different.

They open with a rhetorical question "What better way [exists] to {do something} than {instrumental phrase}.

Instrumental phrases using **with** or **by**:

show ... by {doing} something
show ... with {something}

> You can show your teacher you're a serious student by studying.
>
> You can show your teacher you're a serious student with study.
>
> What better way to show your teacher you're a serious student than by
>   studying?
>
> What better way to show your teacher you're a serious student than
>   with study?